# What determines that which function should be disabled in a locked post?

Tags: discussion, comments, locked-questions, locked

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) locked post, it's only comments that have been disabled and other functions are still being accepted there (e.g. voting, answering, etc.)

Which concrete factor is the reason for disability of *one specific* or more functions to be disabled in a locked post?

For example why it's just the commenting feature that's been disabled in that post and other functions are intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderator discretion.

It was likely determined that *answers* and *upvotes* to the question and other answers (with one notable exception) were useful, but more and more comments were not, likely because of the excessive amount of Zalgo spam that once dominated the comments section of that accepted answer.